# SQL - Sum value when date is part of range

Tags: sql, date, sum, date-range

I have a table with the 5 columns:

```
Account | Service | Value | Start_Date | End_Date
```

I want to pull the value of a specific date for all services by account, but the date may be part of a range rather than the `Start_Date`.

For example: if `Start_Date` on ServiceA is 12/1/2015 and `End_Date` is 12/31/2015 with value of 25 and `Start_Date` on ServiceB is 11/15/2015 and `End_Date` is 12/15/2015 with value of 30.

I am looking to find the sum value (55) for ServiceA and ServiceB on 12/3/2015.

Comment: Since many products are far from ANSI SQL when it comes to date/time, please specify dbms used.

Answer (score 0):

Simply `SUM` the value's for all rows with 12/3/2015 is between start_date and end_date:

```
select sum(value)
from tablename
where '12/3/2015' between Start_Date and End_Date
```

The date literal may need to be adjusted, depending on the dbms used (no dbms tag in question.)

Comment: between is not recommended for Date values in SQL. Try using >=, >, <= and/or =.

Comment: @dpimente, that may be true for some dbms products - but no dbms is specified in the question.